# Is the following equation established?

Tags: fourier-transform

Is the following equation established?

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}s(t)r^*(t)dt=\int_W S(f)R^*(f)df $$
>
> $$s(t)\xrightarrow{\text{Fourier Transform}}S(f) $$
>
> $$r(t)\xrightarrow{\text{Fourier Transform}}R(f) $$

Comment: This property is called unitarity. The Fourier transform is unitary.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac: I'd say that the preservation of the inner product is a consequence of the Fourier transform being unitary, but the stated equation is not the definition of unitarity.

Comment: @MattL. Preservation of the inner product on complex inner product spaces is one possible definition of unitarity. For separable or even finite dimensional spaces it's often replaced by an operator definition $U^\dagger U=\mathrm{id}$, but that's only useful if the inner product is canonically induced.

Comment: That of course assumes the fact that the Fourier transform is a bijection on the space it's defined on.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac: Yes, so preservation of the inner product alone is not sufficient for unitarity. For this reason preservation of the inner product can't be the general definition of unitarity.

Comment: @MattL. it is for bijections. A bijection (or transform in this case) is unitary iff it preserves the inner product.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac: Yes, I think this was the point of misunderstanding. For bijections, preservation of the inner product is sufficient. However, it's not sufficient for operators in general, where we also require the operator to be surjective.

Comment: What about  calling this  "an isometry with respect to the  $L_2$ norm" (provided some integrals exist, and  with proper scaling in the  Fourier transform definition)?

Answer (score 1):

It's a version of [Parseval's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_theorem), which can be easily proved by noting that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}s(t)r^*(t)dt=\mathcal{F}\{s(t)r^*(t)\}\big|_{f=0}\tag{1}$$

where $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier transform. Note that in general the integration limits should be $-\infty$ and $\infty$ for both integrals. I assume your notation refers to band-limited functions.

From $(1)$, the proof is quite short:

$$\mathcal{F}\{s(t)r^*(t)\}=S(f)\star R^*(-f)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}S(\nu)R^*(\nu -f)d\nu\tag{2}$$

where $\star$ denotes convolution. So

$$\mathcal{F}\{s(t)r^*(t)\}\big|_{f=0}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}S(\nu)R^*(\nu)d\nu\tag{3}$$

which establishes the equation in your question.

Comment: But the question arises: what is the Fourier transform of $s(t)r^*(t)$? It took me a few minutes to write down the convolution integral with $S(f)$ and $R^*(f)$, simplify it for the special case $f=0$ etc.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I added the proof. I think it's a bit shorter and simpler than the one you provided, *if* we may assume that those basic Fourier transform correspondences are known (or can be looked up).

Comment: Thanks. As you say, it helps to have under one's belt the result that multiplication in the time domain corresponds to convolution in the frequency domain, and to have the necessary experience in the use of transform theory to realize that it is not necessary to compute a transform and _then_ set $f=0$. A beginning student would likely say that he does not know how to evaluate the integral in $(2)$, and thus $(3)$ would be beyond his reach. Oh, and a +1 too.

Answer (score 0):

If by "Is the following equation established?" you mean, is the equation valid, the answer is **Yes, it has been proved.**  If you want to know a proof of it, here is one.

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty s(t)r^*(t)\,\mathrm dt
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty 
\left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty S(f)e^{j2\pi ft}\,\mathrm df
\right] r^*(t)\,\mathrm dt &\scriptstyle{\text{replace}~s(t)~
\text{with its Fourier integral representation}}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty S(f)\left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty 
r^*(t)e^{j2\pi ft}\,\mathrm dt
\right] \,\mathrm df &\scriptstyle{\text{check that interchange of 
order of integration is valid}}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty S(f)\left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty 
r(t)e^{-j2\pi ft}\,\mathrm dt\right]^* \,\mathrm df
&\scriptstyle{\text{integral of conjugate is conjugate of integral}}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty S(f)[R(f)]^* \,\mathrm df
&\scriptstyle{\text{identify integral in square brackets as Fourier
transform}}
\end{align}